# Typescript compiles `tsx` to a wrong type of modue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, jsx, es6-modules

I'm trying to use Typescript together with Node and React. However I'm struggling to set up the Typescript compiler to use the correct type of the “module convention”. I know that ES6 modules do work correctly, but Typescript always generates a non-standard module syntax that, for some reason, just doesn't work.

.

If I save this code into a `.js` file, it works correctly:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

let logo = require('./logo.svg');

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <p>{logo}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

However, if I save it to a `.tsx` file, it compiles to this:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const react_1 = require("react");
require("./App.css");
let logo = require('./logo.svg');
class App extends react_1.Component {
    render() {
        return (react_1.default.createElement("div", { className: "App" },
            react_1.default.createElement("header", { className: "App-header" },
                react_1.default.createElement("img", { src: logo, className: "App-logo", alt: "logo" }),
                react_1.default.createElement("h1", { className: "App-title" }, "Welcome to React")),
            react_1.default.createElement("p", { className: "App-intro" },
                "To get started, edit ",
                react_1.default.createElement("code", null, "src/App.js"),
                " and save to reload."),
            react_1.default.createElement("p", null, logo)));
    }
}
exports.default = App;
```

Which results in a Node error `react_1.default is undefined`. I tried adding a `esModuleInterop` flag to the Typescript compiler, which added this definition:

```js
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
}
```

and changed `require("react")` to `__importDefault(require("react"))`. That fixes the first problem, however `react_1.Component` is still undefined. Is there a way to set the Typescript compiler to use the standard ES6 modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to `tsconfig.json`:

```js
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "es6"
}
```